# listiterator add method issue

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, iterator

How does list iterator add method work?  Using the code below why doesn't the string "TREEEEEEEEEEEES" get printed when I execute the"List Iterator forward" loop?

```
     public class PracticeClass5 
         {
              @Test
              public void LearningXMLSuite()  
    // Method 1
                  List<String> myarraylist1 = new ArrayList<String>();
                  myarraylist1.add("Oranges");
                  myarraylist1.add("Apples");
                  myarraylist1.add("Strawberries");
                  myarraylist1.add("Watermelon");
                  myarraylist1.add("Cantalope");
                  myarraylist1.add("Berries");
                  myarraylist1.add(6, "banannas");

for (int i=0; i< myarraylist1.size(); i++)
          {
              System.out.println("Fruits " + i +" = " +myarraylist1.get(i));
          }
          System.out.println();
          
          
          ListIterator<String> myitr1 = myarraylist1.listIterator();
          myitr1.add("TREEEEEEEEEEEES"); 




 for (int i=0; i< myarraylist1.size(); i++)
              {
                  System.out.println("After adding " + i +" = " +myarraylist1.get(i));
              }
              System.out.println();
              
              
              
              /// does not work
              while (myitr1.hasNext())
              {
                  System.out.println("List Iterator forward " +myitr1.next());
              }
            
          
              
              System.out.println();
              
              while (myitr1.hasPrevious())
              {
                  System.out.println("List Iterator backward " +myitr1.previous());
              }
            
              System.out.println();
              
                        
            }
        }




**Output**
    Fruits 0 = Oranges  
    Fruits 1 = Apples  
    Fruits 2 = Strawberries  
    Fruits 3 = Watermelon  
    Fruits 4 = Cantaloupe    
    Fruits 5 = Berries  
    Fruits 6 = bananas    
    
    After adding 0 = TREEEEEEEEEEEES  
    After adding 1 = Oranges    
    After adding 2 = Apples   
    After adding 3 = Strawberries    
    After adding 4 = Watermelon  
    After adding 5 = Cantalope  
    After adding 6 = Berries  
    After adding 7 = bananas  
    
    List Iterator forward Oranges    
    List Iterator forward Apples  
    List Iterator forward Strawberries  
    List Iterator forward Watermelon  
    List Iterator forward Cantaloupe  
    List Iterator forward Berries  
    List Iterator forward bananas  
    
    
    List Iterator backward bananas  
    List Iterator backward Berries  
    List Iterator backward Cantaloupe  
    List Iterator backward Watermelon  
    List Iterator backward Strawberries  
    List Iterator backward Apples  
    List Iterator backward Oranges  
    List Iterator backward TREEEEEEEEEEEES
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because iterator does not move forward when you add an element. You have a list:

```
"Oranges"   "Apples"   "Strawberries"   ...
```

When you call `myarraylist1.listIterator()` the Iterator gets created, and it's 'current' (cursor) position is set to be just before `"Oranges"`, like that:

```
                         "Oranges"   "Apples"   "Strawberries"  ...
//Iterator points here ^
```

Then you add an item to the front with `myitr1.add("TREEEEEEEEEEEES")`, but the iterator's cursor does not move, so it looks like that:

```
     "TREEEEEEEEEEEES"   "Oranges"   "Apples"   "Strawberries"  ...
//Iterator points here ^
```

If you call `myitr1.previous()` before your `while (myitr1.hasNext())` loop, it will go one element back, and point to the place you want.

Comment: Thanks, very good explanation about the iterator position.  After adding the myitr1.previous(), it worked.